# Elasticsearch - Filtered query with weighted types

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have inherited an Elasticsearch query that I am trying to modify. The query I have at the moment is:

```
{
  "fields": [

  ],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 51,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "data.*"
          ],
          "default_operator": "AND",
          "query": "*Search term*"
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "type": [
              "typeOne",
              "typeTwo",
              "typeThree"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I have been trying to do is boost one of these terms over the other 2 in the results but have not been able to get it to work. I have tried adding a "boost" value but this has oddly given me the opposite effect - it disables any type that is given a boost.

I tried the following as the "filter" object:

```
"filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "type": "typeOne"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "type": "typeTwo"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "type": "typeThree",
                  "boost": 2
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

But as I said before, instead of boosting "typeThree" it removes all "typeThree" from the results.

Can anyone help me boost a specific term type?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to structure the query to achieve the above , one approach would be using  [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) .It would look something on these lines

Example:

```
"query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "type": "typeThree"
                  }
               },
               "weight": 2
            }
         ],
         "score_mode": "sum",
         "boost_mode": "sum",
         "query": {
            "filtered": {
               "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                     "fields": [
                        "data.*"
                     ],
                     "default_operator": "AND",
                     "query": "*search term*"
                  }
               },
               "filter": [
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "type": [
                           "typeOne",
                           "typeTwo",
                           "typeThree"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

You can enable [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html?q=explain) to see how this affects the scoring

Comment: I am getting the error "No function with the name [weight] is registered." when I try this query. Is this a function that must be enabled or do I need to tweak this query a bit?

Answer (score 1):

While keety's answer was 98% of the way there, it took a bit of extra googling to get it all together. The problem is that "weight" doesn't work here, instead you must use "boost_factor". The final query looks like this:

```
{
    "fields": [

    ],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 51,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "functions": [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "type": "typeOne"
                        }
                    },
                    "boost_factor": 1.2
                },
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "type": "typeTwo"
                        }
                    },
                    "boost_factor": 1.1
                },
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "type": "typeThree"
                        }
                    },
                    "boost_factor": 1
                }
            ],
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost_mode": "sum",
            "query": {
                "filtered": {
                    "query": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "fields": [
                                "data.*"
                            ],
                            "default_operator": "AND",
                            "query": "*search term*"
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "type": [
                                    "typeOne",
                                    "typeTwo",
                                    "typeThree"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice however this is  probably because the es version is < 1.4 [boost_factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_boost_factor) is deprecated and replaced with weight since then